# Multiple Possible Output Types in Perl6

Tags: raku

I'd like to make a function that returns either a `Range` or an `any Junction` made up of multiple `Ranges`.

Eg :

```
sub foo (Range $a, Range $b) {
  if $a.min <= $b.max && $b.min <= $a.max {
    ($a.min < $b.min ?? $a.min !! $b.min)..($a.max < $b.max ?? $a.max !! $b.max) 
  } else {
    ($a|$b)  
  }
}
```

Is there an easy way of adding a Type constraint to the sub to say it could return a `Range` or a `Junction`?

Thought's I've had include

- Multi sub that does the checking in the where clause.
- Subset `Any`.
- Always return a junction and just use one() (But I'd like to keep Ranges of possible)

But if there's a simpler way that someone can think of.

Comment: multi sub with different return value in the signature, feels most natural and most efficient to me.

Comment: Have you considered *always* returning a Junction, but possibly with 1 element?

Comment: I'm thinking about that. I'm currently trying to work out exactly what I'm trying to achieve. :)

Answer (score 14):

Just create a [subset](https://docs.perl6.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-subset-subset) that accommodates both results, and use it as if it were a type.

Note that since a [*Junction*](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Junction) is not a subtype of [*Any*](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Any), you have to mark it as being [*Mu*](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Mu).
([*Junction*](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Junction) specifically can't be [*Any*](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Any) and work the way it does)

```perl6
my subset Range-or-Junction of Mu where Range|Junction;
```

```perl6
proto sub foo ( Range, Range --> Range-or-Junction ) {*}

multi sub foo (Range $a,Range $b where $a.min ~~ $b || $a.max ~~ $b --> Range){
  # note that this is wrong as it doesn't takes into consideration
  # :excludes-min or :excludes-max
  min($a.min,$b.min) .. max($a.max,$b.max)
}
multi sub foo (Range $a,Range $b --> Junction){
  $a | $b
}
```

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp Actually based on the comment Scimon wrote, my guess is that I could have just said that “Junction is of type Mu”, and he would have been able to fill in the rest.